# How to update GeoLite2-Country.mmdb (country by IP database) to newest version in Magnolia CMS?

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia, geolite2

There is Magnolia cms module `magnolia-personalization-traits-1.4.6.jar`. It uses internally GeoLite2 ip-to-country database. Database is stored in a file `info/magnolia/personalization/geoip/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb` which is stored in aforementioned jar file. The problem is that database is quite old and out of date.

I would like to update this database file but cannot see any possibility to do that. I tried to put new version of the database file in identical package in my project but that (obviously) failed. Is there any possibility to to update this file?

edit: I'm using Magnolia v 5.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get newer file first on the class path. Best way to achieve that is to put it in /WEB-INF/classes folder of your Tomcat in folder structure identical to that found in jar file.